# Docker-compose: how can i mount node_modules?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-modules

Im trying to mount node_modules folder in docker-compose file but i cant figure out how i can do that...
docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  test:
    container_name: abc
    restart: unless-stopped
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/node_modules:/data/node_modules
      - ./src:/data/src
      - ./uploads:/data/uploads  
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
WORKDIR /data
COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./package-lock.json .
COPY ./config.json .

RUN npm install
CMD cd ./src/server && node ./server.js
```

What i expect from running `docker-compose up -d` command - i want it to install the node_modules and make a volume for them so i can access/edit some modules from the local machine outside container

And what i get now is empty ./docker/node_modules folder, aswell as empty node_modules folder in the container causing my app to just error about module not found

When i execute `npm install` manually in the container it seems to sync the folders just fine, but why it doesnt with Dockerfile? How can i get it to work?

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Can you install Node on your host system (if it's not there already) and use that instead?  Once you overwrite everything the Dockerfile does with `volumes:` mounts you're not getting a whole lot out of that image, and it sounds like you don't want Docker's filesystem isolation.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean, i have node on the host system but i would like to get `docker-compose up -d` to install the node_modules and to be accessible from the host system, and right now it seems to install them but the folders are empty, when i do `npm install` in the container by myself it appears just fine.